# Programmatically synchronize(camera-link) multiple intersection windows

Tags: ocean, petrel

Ocean2013.1 provides a sample(WheelerViewer) for using cameras(OpenInventor features) for 3D Windows, but is it possible to synchronize(*equivalent of clicking the camera link toolbar option*) multiple intersection windows in Ocean/Petrel programmatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Camera linking is available as a Petrel feature but not as a Ocean API for developer to access programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to be mode specific on what you are trying to synchronize and why.

The Window3D exposes enough camera API that one can write his own camera view synchronization.

If all you want is to be able to click the "Synchronize camera" button via API, it's a different issue. Why do you need this? Often users ask to be able to link all windows with one mouse button click. This, I believe, might be coming in 2015 as a user feature.

Comment: Every run of my application generates  multiple(2) interpretation windows(not Windows3D) and instead of instructing end users to click  _"Interpretation Window->Camera Link"_ button for each of the windows I thought I could use(any existing API) to link them.